# Data not being displayed when selecting two columns MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've created some tables in `MySQL` and I'm trying to select the data that's in those tables so that they get displayed. I have the following tables. `Formed, Track, Album, Band, Customers` and I have got the primary and foreign keys within the tables. I've also used the `Insert into` statement to insert data into the tables so there is data within the tables. I'm trying to get all the albums from a certain band to be displayed and I'm following the example below

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Which can be found at W3Schools, to produce the following statement:

```
SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.Title, Band.BandName
FROM Album
INNER JOIN Band
ON Album.BandID = Band.BandID
ORDER BY Band.BandName;
```

And this statement that I've made does create the table headers but doesn't display any data as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGMz7.png).

**EDIT**

In all the tables I've created, I hav got the primary key as an `int AUTO_INCREMENT`

**EDIT #2**

I've now changed it so that I have:

```
SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.Title, Band.BandName
FROM Band
LEFT JOIN Album
ON Album.BandID = Band.BandID
ORDER BY Band.BandName;
```

Which displays only the band name and gets a `NULL` values for the `AlbumID` and `Title`

**EDIT #3 Completed**

I've managed to edit it so now I have the script working. It's as follows:

```
SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.Title, Band.BandName
FROM Album
LEFT JOIN Band
ON Album.BandName = Band.BandName
ORDER BY Band.BandName;
```

Comment: It's an INNER JOIN, perhaps you don't have common data.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes The data types that I'm using are `Date, varchar, int`

Comment: I mean, an INNER JOIN won't return anything if `Orders.CustomerID!=Customers.CustomerID`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes So it won't return anything if `Orders.CustomerID` is not equal to `Customers.CustomerID`?

Comment: Do a select form Band and Album and show what data is in there. Not all of the data, but at least some rows where BandID is the same in both tables.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand As `Select from` or `Select form`?

Comment: From, sorry for the typo

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I've edited the question (so I have the script detailed under **EDIT #2**) which only displays the band

Comment: Are you making sure you have matching ID values where you're joining?  Like if you have CustomerID = 1 for John Smith in the Customers table do you have any rows that have a CustomerID = 1 in Orders?  If not you're not going to want to use an INNER JOIN and things like LEFT and RIGHT joins will be helpful here.  But at the same time joining when you have 0 IDs that match is somewhat fruitless for what  you're trying to do.

Comment: An INNER JOIN only returns rows where both sides of the JOIN statement exist, so if Orders.CustomerID is not equal to Customers.CustomerID there is no data to display. The same applies if Band.BandID and Album.BandID have no matches; there is no data to display.

Comment: @MikeS I'm using the script that starts `SELECT Album.AlbumID`, the other script that has the `CustomerID` in is one I found online

Comment: @KenWhite I've made some edits so I have got some output, seen in **EDIT #2**

Comment: The fact that changing to a left join returns rows with NULL from Album, verifies that there are NO rows in Album with a matching Band ID.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is not INNER JOIN, and they behave differently. As @bitfiddler says, you've now confirmed why your INNER JOIN didn't work; you have no rows in Album with an Album.BandID = Band.BandID.